# Adding arrows between two forests

Tags: arrows, forest

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[french, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{adjustbox} %j'ai ajouté ce package pour utiliser la commande qui permet de centrer


\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec} %pour utiliser titleformat
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        circle,
        l sep=5mm,
        s sep=25mm,
     },
     [C, fill=black!20,draw
        [A,fill=red!20,draw
            [$\alpha$]
            [B,fill=red!20,draw
                [$\beta$]
                [$\gamma$]
            ]
        ]
        [$\delta$]
    ]
 \end{forest}
 $\longrightarrow$
 \begin{forest}
 for tree={
        circle,
        l sep=5mm,
        s sep=25mm,
     },
    [C, fill=black!20 ,draw
        [B,fill=red!20 ,draw
            [A, fill=red!20, draw
                [$\alpha$]
                [$\beta$]
            ]
            [$\gamma$]
        ]
        [$\delta$]
    ]    
 \end{forest} 

\end{document}
```

[image]
We would like to add two arrows but we can't seem to find the answer. If you could help me it would be great :)
[image]

Answer (score 10):

One way is to place a `tikzpicture` between the forests. Set the baselines using the `baseline` option in `forest`. (That node will become the baseline.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[french, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        circle,
        l sep=5mm,
        s sep=15mm,
     },
     [C, fill=black!20,draw
        [A,fill=red!20,draw, baseline %<--- set baseline for this forest at this node
            [$\alpha$]
            [B,fill=red!20,draw
                [$\beta$]
                [$\gamma$]
            ]
        ]
        [$\delta$]
    ]
 \end{forest}
% 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.text)] %<--- set baseline at this node
\draw[->](0,1)--node[above](A){Rotation droite de $y$}(4,1);
\draw[<-](0,0)--node[below]{Rotation gauche de $x$}(4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
 \begin{forest}
 for tree={
        circle,
        l sep=5mm,
        s sep=15mm,
     },
    [C, fill=black!20 ,draw
        [B,fill=red!20 ,draw, baseline %<--- set baseline for this forest at this node
            [A, fill=red!20, draw
                [$\alpha$]
                [$\beta$]
            ]
            [$\gamma$]
        ]
        [$\delta$]
    ]    
 \end{forest} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Rather than using a separate `tikzpicture`, you could just add the arrows to the first `forest` environment. This is straightforward provided the labels above the arrows are shorter than the arrows.

Here, I consider the case where the label text is longer, as shown in the OP's original picture, and we want to adjust the positioning so that the second tree is not located further from the arrows than the first.

The following code basically ignores the arrows and labels, so they don't affect the bounding box of the first tree, and then adds an undrawn path to match the arrows. In effect, this means both trees are positioned relative to the arrows and the labels spill into existing, empty spaces on each side.

```
\documentclass[french, 12pt,a4paper]{report}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705147/ addaswyd o gwestiwn Caro: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/705120/
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{babel}
\forestset{%
  ABC/.style={%
    for tree={%
      circle,
      l sep'=5mm,
      s sep'=15mm,
      font=\sffamily,
    },
  },
}
\tikzset{%
  arrow betwixt/.style={semithick,>=Stealth},
  arrow label/.style={midway,above,font=\sffamily\footnotesize,inner xsep=0pt},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  ABC,
  [C, fill=black!20
    [A,fill=red!20
        [$\alpha$]
        [B,fill=red!20
            [$\beta$]
            [$\gamma$]
        ]
    ]
    [$\delta$]
  ]
  \begin{scope}[overlay]
    \draw [arrow betwixt,->] ($(!r.center)!.5!(!r2.center)$) coordinate  (a)  (a -| current bounding box.east) coordinate (b) -- ++(25mm,0pt) node [arrow label] {Rotation droite de y}; 
    \draw [arrow betwixt,<-] ($(!r11.center)!.5!(!r122.center)$) coordinate (c)  (c -| b)  -- ++(25mm,0pt) node [arrow label] {Rotation gauche de x};
  \end{scope}
  \path (current bounding box.east) -- ++(25mm,0pt);
\end{forest}%
\begin{forest}
  ABC,
  [C, fill=black!20 
      [B,fill=red!20 
          [A, fill=red!20
              [$\alpha$]
              [$\beta$]
          ]
          [$\gamma$]
      ]
      [$\delta$]
  ]    
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: two trees' relationship shown by arrows]